# Overlaying a GLSurfaceView on top of another SurfaceView causes crash

Tags: android, opengl-es, overlay, transparency, android-relativelayout

I would like to overlay a modified SurfaceView with a GLSurfaceView with a transparent background, but adding the GLSurfaceView on top of the SurfaceView causes the application to crash.

The modified SurfaceView displays a video obtained in realtime from a drone camera, the code is sampled directly from Parrot's SDK sample and it work perfectly. The GLSurfaceView is one that I have created, with a transparent background. For now it just render a green triangle with a transparent background so I should be able to see the video in background.

I have tested the GLSurfaceView in another project and it works, I have tested to overlay an ImageView with it and it also work, but when I try to overlay the (Video)SurfaceView from the real project, it crashes...

Here code of the `GLSurfaceView`:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {


    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
                    dx = dx * -1 ;
                }

                // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                if (x < getWidth() / 2) {
                    dy = dy * -1 ;
                }

                mRenderer.setAngle(
                        mRenderer.getAngle() +
                                ((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));
                requestRender();
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){

        super(context);

        SurfaceView sfvTrack = this;
        //sfvTrack.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
        SurfaceHolder sfhTrackHolder = sfvTrack.getHolder();
        sfhTrackHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

The SurfaceView responsible of the Video sampled from Parrot's SDKSample:

```
public class BebopVideoView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "BebopVideoView";
    private static final String VIDEO_MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";
    private static final int VIDEO_DEQUEUE_TIMEOUT = 33000;

    private MediaCodec mMediaCodec;
    private Lock mReadyLock;

    private boolean mIsCodecConfigured = false;

    private ByteBuffer mSpsBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer mPpsBuffer;

    private ByteBuffer[] mBuffers;

    private static final int VIDEO_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int VIDEO_HEIGHT = 368;

    public BebopVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        customInit();
    }

    public BebopVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        customInit();
    }

    public BebopVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        customInit();
    }

    private void customInit() {
        mReadyLock = new ReentrantLock();
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public void displayFrame(ARFrame frame) {
        mReadyLock.lock();

        if ((mMediaCodec != null)) {
            if (mIsCodecConfigured) {
                // Here we have either a good PFrame, or an IFrame
                int index = -1;

                try {
                    index = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(VIDEO_DEQUEUE_TIMEOUT);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error while dequeue input buffer");
                }
                if (index >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer b;
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        b = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffer(index);
                    } else {
                        b = mBuffers[index];
                        b.clear();
                    }

                    if (b != null) {
                        b.put(frame.getByteData(), 0, frame.getDataSize());
                    }

                    try {
                        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, frame.getDataSize(), 0, 0);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error while queue input buffer");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Try to display previous frame
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int outIndex;
            try {
                outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);

                while (outIndex >= 0) {
                    mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                    outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while dequeue input buffer (outIndex)");
            }
        }


        mReadyLock.unlock();
    }

    public void configureDecoder(ARControllerCodec codec) {
        mReadyLock.lock();

        if (codec.getType() == ARCONTROLLER_STREAM_CODEC_TYPE_ENUM.ARCONTROLLER_STREAM_CODEC_TYPE_H264) {
            ARControllerCodec.H264 codecH264 = codec.getAsH264();

            mSpsBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(codecH264.getSps().getByteData());
            mPpsBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(codecH264.getPps().getByteData());
        }

        if ((mMediaCodec != null) && (mSpsBuffer != null)) {
            configureMediaCodec();
        }

        mReadyLock.unlock();
    }

    private void configureMediaCodec() {
        mMediaCodec.stop();
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", mSpsBuffer);
        format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", mPpsBuffer);

        mMediaCodec.configure(format, getHolder().getSurface(), null, 0);
        mMediaCodec.start();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        }

        mIsCodecConfigured = true;
    }

    private void initMediaCodec(String type) {
        try {
            mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
        }

        if ((mMediaCodec != null) && (mSpsBuffer != null)) {
            configureMediaCodec();
        }
    }

    private void releaseMediaCodec() {
        if (mMediaCodec != null) {
            if (mIsCodecConfigured) {
                mMediaCodec.stop();
                mMediaCodec.release();
            }
            mIsCodecConfigured = false;
            mMediaCodec = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mReadyLock.lock();
        initMediaCodec(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
        mReadyLock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mReadyLock.lock();
        releaseMediaCodec();
        mReadyLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The layout of the concerned activity (only the first two blocks are related to the question):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".sample.BebopActivity"
    android:id="@+id/piloting_view">

    <pact44.drone.sample.BebopVideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <pact44.image3d.lucien.MyGLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Emergency"
        android:id="@+id/emergencyBt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:width="150dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take picture"
        android:id="@+id/takePictureBt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:width="150dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/takeOffOrLandBt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:width="150dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right"
        android:id="@+id/yawRightBt"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left"
        android:id="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:width="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left"
        android:id="@+id/yawLeftBt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gazUpBt"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gazUpBt"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/gazUpBt"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right"
        android:id="@+id/rollRightBt"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/backBt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backBt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backBt"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="up"
        android:id="@+id/gazUpBt"
        android:layout_above="@+id/yawRightBt"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/yawRightBt"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/yawRightBt"
        android:width="110dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="down"
        android:id="@+id/gazDownBt"
        android:width="110dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yawRightBt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yawLeftBt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/yawLeftBt"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="forward"
        android:id="@+id/forwardBt"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gazUpBt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:width="110dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="back"
        android:id="@+id/backBt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:width="110dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download"
        android:id="@+id/downloadBt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:width="150dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Battery: "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="XXX%"
        android:id="@+id/batteryLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="roll"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rollLeftBt"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="yaw"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gazDownBt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gazDownBt"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried to create and add the GLSurfaceView manually without xml, but it crashes when I use `addContentView(myGLSurfaceView, myRelativeLayoutParams)`.

Thanks for reading, have a nice day.

**Edit:** Here is the crash report when I add the GLSurfaceView from the xml:

```
04-12 21:20:40.631 17164-17164/pact44.droneracingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: pact44.droneracingapp, PID: 17164
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pact44.droneracingapp/pact44.drone.sample.BebopActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class pact44.image3d.lucien.MyGLSurfaceView
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class pact44.image3d.lucien.MyGLSurfaceView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at pact44.drone.sample.BebopActivity.onCreate(BebopActivity.java:40)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class pact44.image3d.lucien.MyGLSurfaceView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:628)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at pact44.drone.sample.BebopActivity.onCreate(BebopActivity.java:40) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                                           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:592)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at pact44.drone.sample.BebopActivity.onCreate(BebopActivity.java:40) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The line 40 of *BebopActivity.java* correspond to the instruction `setContentView(mylayoutwhodoesnotwork);`. When the GlSurfaceView is added from pure java, the line causing the error correspond to the instruction `addContentView(myAwesomeGLSurfaceView);`.

I don't see any particular error in the code, it seems to me that what I am trying to do, i.e., putting those two `SurfaceView` in the same activity, one overlaying the other, is not possible... If that is the case, creating two activities, the one above having a transparent background, seems a possible solution but the system could stop the background activity causing the video to stop...

Comment: can you add you crush report ??

Comment: Yes, added now.

Comment: it is possible to work with one surfaceview and one GLSurfaceView where one overlaying other. You can also overlay two GLSurfaceView.  I will post my code soon one GLSurfaceView overlaying a surfaceview

Comment: Yes, as long as we can overlay two `SurfaceView` it should work with any `SurfaceView`... But why does it crash?
MyGLSurfaceView works perfectly when I test it alone in another  activity, I can use it to overlay other `SurfaceView`s (only tested with an `ImageView` but that should be enough). `BebopActivity` works perfectly fine when I don't add `MyGLSurfaceView`, but as soon as I try to add it, it crashes.

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, try adding the `MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor to your MyGlSurfaceView class. I get your error when I remove that constructor from my own code.